# Cardview not displaying in android studio 3.5.1

Tags: java, android, android-cardview, androidx, android-studio-3.5.1

I have tried `CardView` library on the older android studio version 3.3.1 and the code was working. The emulator was displaying the correct images. But, I switched to the new version 3.5 nothing is displaying in the `CardView`, not even a `TextView`.

xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="#fcfcfc"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1">

    <!-- A CardView that contains a TextView -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Gradle:

```
dependencies {

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'

}
```

Comment: google replaced all materia desine componentd to single library implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0', just import this lib and remove cardview lib

Comment: @HarishReddy It is not totally correct.  There is also an andriodx implementation of CardView.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView //XML Section
```

Add [**`AndroidX`**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx) dependency

```
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
```

Comment: It is not totally correct. There are 2 different implementations of `CardView`. The androidx library (`androidx.cardview.widget.CardView`) and the material components library (`com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView`). If you want to use the first one, you don't need the material compoments library.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti indeed sir.

Answer (score 2):

You **can't** use support and andriodx libraries together.

Change

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
```

And use `androidx.cardview.widget.CardView` in your layout/code.

There is another implementation of the `CardView`.
It is included in the [**Material Components Library**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialCardView.md)

Just add:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

and in your xml you can use:

```
 <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
  ...>
```

**They are different:**

`MaterialCardView` **extends** `androidx.cardview.widget.CardView` and provides all of the features of CardView, but adds attributes for customizing the stroke and uses an updated Material style by default.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Android Studio 3.5.1. It worked for me:

dependencies {

`def cardview_version = "1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:$cardview_version"
   }

and xml: