# Could not find cardview.jar (androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-cardview, androidx, materialcardview

My project worked fine but today when I opened that, that has this error, although I didn't use any cardview. My other project build fine but only that project doesn't build.

Could not find cardview.jar (androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0).

my class path is: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'

I have added cardview library manually but it didn't work too.

I have added

```
maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
```

but it didn't work too.

I have added cardview library manually but it didn't work too.

this is my gradle code project level

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and this is my gradle code app level

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.intechdev.tcommerce"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.9'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.tiper:MaterialSpinner:1.3.3'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:4.0.2'
    implementation "androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0"
    implementation 'com.iarcuschin:simpleratingbar:0.1.5'
    annotationProcessor "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0"
    implementation "com.github.firdausmaulan:GlideSlider:1.5.1"
    api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.justkiddingbaby:vercodeedittext:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-beta01'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Comment: read https://stackoverflow.com/a/58481722/3395198

Comment: I have added this library and android get error failed to resolve androidx.cardview.cardview:1.0.0

Comment: post your `app/build.gradle` file

Comment: I edited my post and added gradle files code @H.sanati

Comment: remove `androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0` from build.gradle and use  `<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView` in xml. and use `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'`

Comment: I didn't use and I don't want to use cardview. my app doesn't have cardview. When I opened the project, it has the error and I tried to fix that so I added that dependecy. I don't need cardview and never used that for that app!!! @IntelliJAmiya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove

```
    implementation "com.github.firdausmaulan:GlideSlider:1.5.1"
```

and use another slider library.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't add the CardView library.

add this to your dependencies in a new line:

```
 implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
```

and then sync your Gradle files it should solve the problem.

Comment: and make sure you connected with VPN if you are from restricted countries

Comment: When I add this dependency android studio gets this error: ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.cardview.cardview:1.0.0:
Affected Modules: app. I always use VPN

Answer (score 0):

The Gradle version is not compatible with your Android Studio version.
In this section, upgrade your Gradle version

> File > ProjectStructure > Project